# IE 9 Browser freeze after selecting text

Tags: asp.net

IE 9 Browser freeze after selecting text "Sample Data" disabled textbox in asp.net

`<asp:TextBox ID="FirstName" runat="server" Text="Sample Data" Enabled="false" />`

Comment: Never experienced such things. Do other browsers work? As a workaround try using a css-class which disables the textbox.

Comment: Sorry, is there a question here?

Comment: This cannot be the actual issue. Try to find the actual problem. Forget about the disabled textbox.